# Client-side oriented website approach name (less server-side code, more client-side code)

Tags: terminology, websites

I have a terminology question.

I was searching about tips to design a website that is using less server-side code and more client-side code, and realized I don't really know which exact term to search if there is one. Example: Maximizing CDNs usage for library, using widgets when possible, integration of client-side social-media SDKs.

So my question is not about tips themselves, but about the existence of such a term.

Edit:
I already know about SPAs and Client-Side Javascript Frameworks. This is what brings me to wonder if there's a name to an approach where you focus on client-side code at a point that you maximize external resources.

Comment: I take it my suggestion of searching for "Client-Side Javascript Frameworks" or "Client-Side HTML5 Frameworks" didn't work for you.

Comment: You seem to be deeply focused on what this thing is called.  Why? If you must know, it's called "Client-Server" or "Fat Client."  The opposite approach is "Thin-client" or "Multi-tier."

Comment: I'm currently using knockout. But yes, without a client-side JS framework, only using client code to display data wouldn't be imaginable.

Comment: @Robert Yes, how it is called is what is interesting me. Knowing how a thing is called is often useful when the core of the problem is 'how can I search for this'.

Comment: So I'm taking your comment as an answer.

Comment: You mean the "fat client" one?  It's not especially meaningful; you'll get much better mileage if you search for "client-side frameworks," and let your explorations happen from there.

Comment: `Fat client` actually led me to other interesting questions on SE about external resources and widgets, but yes, starting from client-side framework is way more prolific. Thanks.

Comment: May be its time to coin a new term if there exists no term for this

Answer (score 3):

What if we flip this around and talk about how the client and server *interacts* and not necessarily which has *more code*. I've seen this called (and this is a phrase I like):

API-centric

Comment: Interesting term. If the server-side code is not there to provide the MVC algorithms since a JS client-side framework is already doing most of the job, then it's only there to provide some functions and resources, thus API-centric. I'll try this keyword in my searches too.

Answer (score 1):

I can't guarantee less server-side code, but you might want to search for:

- `Single Page Applications` (a.k.a. SPAs)

Comment: Thanks. I would make such websites SPAs for sure. I'm just wondering if there's a name for an approach like the one I'm describing. Because using less server-side code and maximizing external ressources usage is definitively an approach which has a lot of repercussions on a website design.